# What’s the word for someone who mistakenly thinks everyone cares about what they do?

Tags: single-word-requests

Some people say things like “I’m gonna do this, and I don’t care what you all think!” but no one cares about what they do anyway. What’s the word for that person?

I’ve considered self-centred and insecure, but I feel those are too broad for such a specific thing. I tried looking it up, but it would give me answers for different things in relation. Compound words and phrases are fine but I would prefer a single word.

Comment: *Narcissistic* or *bigheaded*

Comment: Many terms are suggested in the former thread; 'self-important' ('having an exaggerated sense of one's own value or importance', [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/self-important)) is perhaps the best fit. Others realise that one isn't all that important.

Answer (score 0):

Your choice may depend on what you want to emphasize—the behavior, the motivation/personality behind it, or the reaction of others. There are many possibilities.

**arrogant**

> 1: Making or having the disposition to make unwarrantable claims of rank or estimation; giving one's self an undue degree of importance.
> [Century Dictionary](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Century_dictionary/PZ6nlaaBWuwC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=Making%20,%20or%20having%20the%20disposition%20to%20make%20,%20exhorbitant%20claims%20of%20rank%20or%20estimation%20%3B%20giving%20oneself%20an%20undue%20degree%20of%20importance%20%3B%20presumptiously&pg=PA321&printsec=frontcover) (1906)

> 2: showing an offensive attitude of superiority : proceeding from or characterized by arrogance
> *an arrogant reply* [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/arrogant)
>
> **arrogance**
> an attitude of superiority manifested in an overbearing manner or in presumptuous claims or assumptions [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/arrogance)

> Indeed, I'd like to suggest that this kind of **arrogant** front is
> actually only a more sophisticated approach to avoiding
> responsibility. By acting in a sufficiently obnoxious manner, you can
> ensure that nobody will listen to your objections, regardless of their
> merit. [ref](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Rethinking_Systems_Analysis_Design/_mvgif1XRNAC?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=arrogant%20nobody%20is%20listening&dq=arrogant%20nobody%20is%20listening&printsec=frontcover)

> And George doesn't care if people don't like him; he's spent his
> entire life knowing that. In fact, some of the **Arrogant** Georges I know
> consider their unpopularity a badge of honor. [ref](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Finding_the_Next_Steve_Jobs/xdGKBAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=arrogant%20i%20don%27t%20care&pg=PA35&printsec=frontcover)